# Stripe Wordpress Config

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, stripe-payments

I'm trying to recreate the subscription example that Stripe uses here:
https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/subscription-signup

When I submit a test payment, it seems to go thru on the page, but then redirects to www.mysite.com/create_subscription.php, and throws me a 404 as the page doesn't exist. Is there an easier way to do this without using a plugin?

**Form**

```
<form action="/create_subscription.php" method="POST">
              <script
                src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                data-key="test-key"
                data-image="images/marketplace.png"
                data-name="Emma's Farm CSA"
                data-description="Subscription for 1 weekly box"
                data-amount="2000"
                data-label="Sign Me Up!">
              </script>
            </form>
```

**Server side code**

```
<?php // manually load stripe contents 

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/theme-name/stripe-php/init.php');


// (switch to the live key later)
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("test-key");

try
{
  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    'email' => $_POST['stripeEmail'],
    'source'  => $_POST['stripeToken'],
    'plan' => 'test-plan(number)'
  ));

  header('Location: thankyou.html');
  exit;
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  header('Location:oops.html');
  error_log("unable to sign up customer:" . $_POST['stripeEmail'].
    ", error:" . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: This, quite honestly, is NOT the WordPress way. So - either this is NOT a WordPress scenario, or you need to do some research on the proper way to do things like this in WordPress.  (It's SO much that should change that it's not practical to explain how / why in this context).